# Batch watermark images and append wildcard number

Tags: windows, batch

I'm using irfanview to batch process images it has the ability to add watermark to it as well, I want to be able to add a wildcard number after the watermark text, at the moment it just adds the predefined text and it doesn't accept the # that's used to append a incremental number whilst renaming the file.

Is there a way around it or any other program that will allow me to do this? i've seen loads of free batch processors which can add watermark but yet to find one that'll add an incremental number to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, using free [ImBatch](http://www.highmotionsoftware.com/products/imbatch) program you can use tags for metainfo to be included in the text watermark. You can set two watermarking tasks to process in one go - first for you static watermark and the second one for your dynamic one.

PS. I just tested and it seems ImBatch can do exactly the thing you are looking for. Add "Watermark text" to the batch task list in ImBatch, then click on "Plus" button near "Text" field and select "File attributes - Current Index" there to include the tag for the incremental number

Comment: Excellent thank you, I'll give it a go and update.